# Building a clustered plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to plot a clustered plot with points with my data as below

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
dat1 = data.frame(val = rnorm(20, 0, 1), class1 = rep('a', 20), class2 = rep('X', 20))
dat2 = data.frame(val = rnorm(20, 0, 1), class1 = rep('b', 20), class2 = rep('X', 20))
dat3 = data.frame(val = rnorm(20, 0, 1), class1 = rep('a', 20), class2 = rep('Y', 20))
dat4 = data.frame(val = rnorm(20, 0, 1), class1 = rep('b', 20), class2 = rep('Y', 20))
dat = rbind(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4)

ggplot(dat, aes(y = val)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = class2, color = class1))
```

With this I am getting below plot

[image]

As you see the points corresponding to `class1` is mixed in a single column for both `X & Y`. However I want to keep the points corresponding to `class1 = a` and `class1 = b` side-by-side, with may be of little separated space between them.

Is there any way to achieve this using `ggplot`?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: `ggplot(dat, aes(y = val)) + geom_point(aes(x = class2, color = class1), position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a perfect time to use facets:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = class1, color = class1, y = val)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(class2))
```

[image]

If you prefer your original structure and just want a little space added, we can use `position = position_dodge` while specifying a `group` aesthetic that accounts for both `class1` and `class2`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y = val, x = class2, color = class1)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = interaction(class1, class2)),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.1))
```

[image]